# Ruby : In user name last name not present?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
 def fullname           
  "#{first_name} #{last_name}"  
 end
```

If first name and last name not present or either one of them 
 Then how to assign empty string instead of error
 how to concatenate empty string if last name not present ?

Comment: ruby `interpolation` handle this scenario itself no need to handle error externally it automatically return blank string

Comment: @anjali, See my answer below, and I explained it well your issue right here.

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
def fullname  
   if first_name.blank? && last_name.blank? 
      self.first_name= ""
      self.last_name= "" 
   elsif first_name.blank?
      self.first_name= ""
   elsif last_name.blank?
      self.last_name= ""
   else
   end

  "#{first_name} #{last_name}"  
end
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you must make sure that your variables are defined. Because rails will not error even though your variable has `nil` or `empty string ('')` value. For example:

```
first_name = ''
=> ""

first_name = nil
=> nil
```

If your method is from model, you should do like:

```
def fullname
  [self.first_name, self.last_name].join(' ')
end
```

If it is from helpers, you should pass on parameters:

```
def fullname(first_name, last_name)
  [first_name, last_name].join(' ')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try simple logic.

```
"#{first_name if first_name.present?} #{last_name if last_name.present?}".strip
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simple define the `full_name` like this:

```
def full_name
  [first_name, last_name].select(&:present?).join(' ')
end
```

So if `first_name` or `last_name` is blank, it will be ignored when joining!